# crear un trigger que no permita modificar un campo especifico y que si permita modificar los demas campos

Tags: sql, sql-server, trigger

Alguien podria ayudarme a resolver este ejercicio porfavor

Es sobre una BD que lleve el control de un sistema de ventas de una tienda

Las tablas que tengo creadas son

- productos (id, codigoBarra, nombre,precio, stock)
- vendedores (nombre, rut, codigo, email)
- ventas (codigoVenta, idProducto, cantidad, fecha, monto, vendedor)

El ejercicio me pide:

**"Construir un TRIGGER llamado TRG_ACTUALIZACION que no permita modificar el
codigoBarra de un producto, y que cuando se modifique el precio, este no pueda ser 30% más bajo
o más alto que el precio anterior. Luego que se muestre por pantalla los datos nuevos y los antiguos"**

Lo que tengo hecho hasta el momento es esto:

- Pude crear el codigo para que no se modifique el codigo de barra de un producto
- pero no se me ocurre hacerlo cuando se modifica el precio.

Podrian ayudarme con el campo precio porfavor.

```
CREATE TRIGGER trg_actualizacion ON productos

AFTER UPDATE

AS 

BEGIN

    IF UPDATE(codigo_barra)
    BEGIN
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
    END

    IF UPDATE(precio)
    BEGIN
        SELECT deleted.precio AS 'Registro Anterior',
               inserted.precio AS 'Registro Actualizado'
        FROM deleted
        JOIN inserted ON deleted.precio = inserted.precio
    END
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

Este trigger puedes usar, lo comenté y usé `PRINT` para que sepas lo que hace

```
ALTER TRIGGER trg_actualizacion ON productos

AFTER UPDATE

AS

BEGIN

SET ROWCOUNT 0;
SET NOCOUNT ON;


IF UPDATE(codigoBarra)
BEGIN
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
    RAISERROR ('No puede modificar columna [codigoBarra]',16,1);
END

IF UPDATE(precio)
BEGIN

    DECLARE @precioAntes AS FLOAT
    DECLARE @precioNuevo AS FLOAT
    DECLARE @precio30menos AS FLOAT
    DECLARE @precio30mas AS FLOAT

    SELECT @precioAntes = deleted.precio, 
           @precioNuevo = inserted.precio
    FROM deleted
    JOIN inserted ON deleted.id = inserted.id

    -- Obtienes el precio actual +30% y -30%
    SET @precio30menos = @precioAntes * 0.7
    SET @precio30mas = @precioAntes * 1.3

    PRINT @precio30menos
    PRINT @precio30mas

    -- Si el precio nuevo está dentro del rango antes calculado, sigues con el update
    IF (@precioNuevo > @precio30menos) AND (@precioNuevo < @precio30mas)
    BEGIN
        PRINT 'COMMIT';
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        -- Caso contrario, rollback a la transaccion
        PRINT 'ROLLBACK';
        RAISERROR ('No puede modificar columna [precio]',16,1);
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
        RETURN;
    END
        
END

END
```